# Make PDF with form have text fields that copies the other text field

Tags: forms, pdf

I have a PDF with a form so the client can change the value.

The PDF got 8 editable text fields, and they need to have the same value for each PDF.

So is there a way to make it so they don't have to type in the same thing 8 times?

So when they for example write "Horse" in one field, it will change in the 7 other text fields?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, i just need to call them the same. Then if i type smth into one text field "name", it copies over to the other "name".